# Generate ClientHello and ServerHello using node

Tags: node.js, tls1.2

I would like to generate `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` messages using `NodeJs` for testing purposes.

Is there an easy way to generate these messages using NodeJS API (the HTTPS all ready doing it but I can't find where).

If I can't use an existing API then how do I create the simplest messages according to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc524) using NodeJS (How to build the messages in a Buffer correctly)

Comment: Did you found anything?